# Gridgain node discovery and gridcache

Tags: datagrid, gridgain

I start the grid gain node using G.start(gridConfiguration), the node automatically joins the existing nodes.After this I start loading the GridCache ( which is configured to be LOCAL ).

This works fine, but is there is way to access the Grid Cache without doing the G.start(gridConfiguration), since I would like to load the LOCAL cache first and then have the node being detected by other nodes once the cache is loaded succesfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have GridGain started in order to use it's API's. After the grid is started, you can access it using `GridGain.grid().cache(...)` method.

What you can do, for example, is use distributed count down latch (`GridCacheCountDownLatch`) which is exactly the same as `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` class. Then you can have other nodes wait on the latch while your local cache is loading. Once loading is done, you can call `latch.countDown()` and other nodes will be able to proceed.

More information on count-down-latch, as well as other concurrent data structures in GridGain can be found in [documentation](http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Distributed+Data+Structures).